# How to resolve exception attempting to load java class in DB2 Java Stored procedure?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2, mainframe, java-stored-procedures

I have created Java.sqlj program and done with creating packages and jar, when attempting to call the procedure, facing the error like

> ATTEMPTING‬‎ ‪TO‬‎ ‪LOAD‬‎ ‪JAVA‬‎ ‪CLASS‬‎ ‪s1‬‎.‪S1Sal‬‎ ‪FROM‬‎ ‪JAR‬‎ ‪COEDB‬‎.‪S1SAL‬‎

Here s1‬‎.‪S1Sal - Where s1 is the package name and S1Sal is class name and it's defined in the java program.

Error
‪

```
Run‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪SYSPROC‬‎.‪S1NUM‬‎(‪DECIMAL‬‎(‪4‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪0‬‎)‪‬‎)‪

‬‪‬‎{‪call‬‎ ‪SYSPROC‬‎.‪S1NUM‬‎(‪‬‎?‪‬‎)‪‬‎}‪
‬‪USER‬‎-‪DEFINED‬‎ ‪ROUTINE‬‎ ‪SYSPROC‬‎.‪S1NUM‬‎ ‪ENCOUNTERED‬‎ ‪AN‬‎ ‪ EXCEPTION‬‎ ‪ATTEMPTING‬‎ ‪TO‬‎ ‪LOAD‬‎ ‪JAVA‬‎ ‪CLASS‬‎ ‪s1‬‎.‪S1Sal‬‎ ‪FROM‬‎ ‪JAR‬‎ ‪COEDB‬‎.‪S1SAL‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪ ORIGINAL‬‎ ‪EXCEPTION‬‎:‪‬‎ ‪‬‎(‪none‬‎)‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪20212‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪46103‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪22‬‎.‪29
‬‪Run‬‎ ‪of‬‎ ‪routine‬‎ ‪failed‬‎.‪
‬‪‬‎ ‪‬‎-‪‬‎ ‪Roll‬‎ ‪back‬‎ ‪completed‬‎ ‪successfully‬‎.‪
```

Comment: What does the corresponding DSNX961 message displayed on the z/OS system console tell you?

Comment: @cschneid  +DSNX961I  DSNX9WLJ ATTEMPT TO PERFORM OPERATION CreateJavaVM  957 FAILED FOR ROUTINE . .  SSN= DB11     PROC= DB11WLMJ ASID= 00A2   CLASS=  METHOD=  ERROR INFO= FAILURE IN CreateJavaVM: not enough  memory.  | Am getting the above error could ypu please help me to recitfy it . Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you report these error messages to your support staff.  They will have the requisite authority to alter parameters to mitigate the problem, or they might recommend changes to the stored procedure such that it uses less memory.